# Replacing text within string that contains serialize arrays

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, serialization

Thanks for clicking on the question. I am trying to find and replace text within a string that contains serialize arrays. For example :

```
'fgm2wc_options', 'a:19:{s:15:"automatic_empty";N;s:3:"url";s:25:"http://example.com/store/";s:8:"hostname";s:9:"localhost";s:4:"port";s:4:"3306";s:8:"database";s:22:"apgadmin_store_magento";s:8:"username" ... }
```

I want to change http://example.com/ to smth else I can do it with str_replace but it will not change the string length indicator ( e.g s:25 ).

This is a function i am using:

```
function recursive_unserialize_replace( $old_url = '', $new_url = '', $data = '', $serialised = false ) {
    $new_url = rtrim( $new_url, '/' );
    $data = explode( ', ', $data );

    try {
        if ( is_string( $data ) && ( $unserialized = @unserialize( $data ) ) !== false ) {
            $data = recursive_unserialize_replace( $old_url, $new_url, $unserialized, true );
        } elseif ( is_array( $data ) ) {
            $_tmp = array( );

            foreach ( $data as $key => $value ) {
                $_tmp[ $key ] = recursive_unserialize_replace( $old_url, $new_url, $value );
            }

            $data = $_tmp;
            unset( $_tmp );
        } else {
            if ( is_string( $data ) ) {
                $data = str_replace( $old_url, $new_url, $data );
            }   
        }

        if ( $serialised ) {
            return serialize( $data );
        }
    } catch( Exception $error ) {

    }

    return $data;
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Why are you doing this?  Why not simply maintain the data you need to manipulate as a compound datatype like an array?

Comment: @GordonM The data is from an uploaded file that I read as a string, is there a way to read it as an array?

Comment: Why not unserializing, updating the original structure and then serializing back again?

Comment: @OfirBaruch has the right idea. What you did, OP, just begs for error to happen.

Comment: @OfirBaruch How can I unserialize the whole 16k lines long string?

Comment: If you persistently want to use regex, 25 is strlen of the string. Set length of a new string.

Comment: @splash58 I am sorry mate I cannot think of a regex that will catch all the length indicators before the searched string and replaced with the strlen of the new string. Can you help ?

Comment: str_replace ('s:25:"http://example.com/store/"', 's:3:"New"', $str);

Comment: First of all, what's the structure of your string? Any reasonable person would assume that if you do `$data = explode( ', ', $data );` you can then do `$array = unserialize($data[1])` and work with the array entries

Comment: @splash58 this will catch this case only but in the string, I can have numerous encounters of the url that i need to replace

Comment: @apokryfos Its a database structure. When I "unserialize( $value )" in the foreach it returns false.

Comment: Based on what you shared the first entry is not a serialized array but the 2nd one is so you can't unserialize every single array entry you've exploded. That's why it's important to know what structure your data is in. Is <string>, <serialized array> or something else?

Comment: @apokryfos after the explode I have an array that contains strings but not every string is SA that is what I am trying to address to unserialize only those strings ( sadly atm even when I try to unserialize all the values the unserialize() returns false for every single string. ). There is no structure pattern I can follow

Comment: Then do a `preg_match("/a:\d+:\{/",$value)` to determine if it's a serialized array or not. At any rate don't directly manipulate serialized data because they are binary strings and are not meant to be manipulated using normal string operations.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested  this is the solution i came up with:

```
function unserialize_replace( $old_url = '', $new_url = '', $database_string = '' ) {
    if ( substr( $old_url, -1 ) !== '/' ) {
        $new_url = rtrim( $new_url, '/' );
    }

    $serialized_arrays = preg_match_all( "/a:\d+:.*\;\}+/", $database_string, $matches );

    if( !empty( $serialized_arrays ) && is_array( $matches ) ) {
        foreach ( $matches[ 0 ] as $match ) {
            $unserialized = @unserialize( $match );

            if ( $unserialized ) {
                $buffer = str_replace( $old_url, $new_url, $unserialized );
                $buffer = serialize( $buffer );

                $database_string = str_replace( $match, $buffer, $database_string );
            }
        }
    }

    if ( is_string( $database_string ) ) {
        $database_string = str_replace( $old_url, $new_url, $database_string );
    }

    return $database_string;
}
```

Thanks for the suggestions. Please let me know if you see anything wrong and anything i can improve